# Run function when a user clicks a button?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call a function using the appended button in the appended table.

Here is my code snippet.

```
function userAction(){
    window.alert("Hi");
   }

var newbtn=document.createElement('button');

   newbtn.setAttribute('type','button');
   newbtn.setAttribute('onclick',userAction);
   newbtn.setAttribute('class','btn btn-primary mt-4');
   newbtn.innerHTML='Review'
   tr.appendChild(newbtn);
```

Click below link for the full code

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t6M5L_6tXYdGnemI8t0qlcFb93jkbx0I/view?usp=sharing
```

I expect it to create a pop up alert when the user clicks the button, but it doesn't seem to be working. This is what the element looks like when I inspect it:

```
<button type="button" onclick="function userAction(){
    window.alert(&quot;Hi&quot;);
     }" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Review</button>
```

What might I be doing incorrectly? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [Click Event Listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) like so instead of setAttribute:

```
newbtn.addEventListener('click', () => userAction());
```

Answer (score 2):

[onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) is a property  and not an attribute. Hence you cannot use setAttribute.

Change it from:

```
newbtn.setAttribute('onclick',userAction);
```

to:

```
newbtn.onclick = userAction;
```

```js
function userAction(){
    window.alert("Hi");
}

 var tr = document.querySelector('tr');
var newbtn=document.createElement('button');

newbtn.setAttribute('type','button');
newbtn.onclick = userAction;
newbtn.setAttribute('class','btn btn-primary mt-4');
newbtn.innerHTML='Review'
tr.appendChild(newbtn);
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>simple cell</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```